# Get array of indices for array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
a = np.array([[9,9,9],[9,0,9],[9,9,9]])
```

I'd like to get an array of each index in that array, like so:

```
i = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],...])
```

One way of doing this that I've found is like this, using `np.indices`:

```
i = np.transpose(np.indices(a.shape)).reshape(a.shape[0] * a.shape[1], 2)
```

But that seems somewhat clumsy, especially given the presence of `np.nonzero` which *almost* does what I want.

Is there a built-in numpy function that will produce an array of the indices of every item in a 2D numpy array?

Comment: Another method that just occurred to me is `np.transpose(np.nonzero(a == a))`, but that's almost *more* weird than using `indices` and `reshape`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one more concise way (if the order is not important):

```
In [56]: np.indices(a.shape).T.reshape(a.size, 2)
Out[56]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

If you want it in your intended order you can use `dstack`:

```
In [46]: np.dstack(np.indices(a.shape)).reshape(a.size, 2)
Out[46]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

For the first approach if you don't want to use `reshape` another way is concatenation along the first axis using `np.concatenate()`.

```
np.concatenate(np.indices(a.shape).T)
```

Comment: The order of the indices doesn't really matter, I guess. I'll go with the first one. Thanks!

Comment: The first one doesn't really work. Try it on `a = np.zeros((2, 2))`.

Comment: Actually, already in the (3,3) example: you can see (1, 2) occurring twice, while (2, 1) is missing

Comment: Hmm.. good point. Perhaps I'll use `np.transpose(np.indices(a.shape)).reshape(a.size, 2)` instead

Comment: @Samadi Noe just add a `T` in the middle of two methods.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes actually it was a mistake made by copy pasting from terminal. Thanks for the note tho.